# Multiple kernel modules intercepting same system call and crash during unload

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module, panic

I'm working on system call interception (for `open()` system call) and I got one problem: I have two kernel modules (`mod1` and `mod2`) and both of them are trying to intercept `open()` syscall. I've loaded `mod1` first and then `mod2`. The `mod1` intercepted `open()` by:

```
original_open1 = sys_call_table[__NR_open];
sys_call_table[__NR_open] = mod1_open;
```

Here `original_open1` would be `sys_open`.
After this, `mod2` intercepted `open()` by:

```
original_open2 = sys_call_table[__NR_open];
sys_call_table[__NR_open] = mod2_open;
```

Here, `original_open2` would be `mod1_open()` since mod1 was loaded first.
Now, the problem is: Suppose I unload `mod1` first and `open()` system call gets executed, then  `mod2_open()` would get called, which ultimately calls `mod1_open()`.

Since `mod1` is already unloaded, calling `mod1_open()` would cause panic (since the function pointer is no longer a valid memory region).

I need some mechanism to avoid this problem. Basically, I want a solution which facilitates loading/unloading the modules (which intercept same syscall) in any random order without causing any panic.

Comment: I think due to the kind of dependency you have between the modules, you must preserve the order in which you unload the modules.

Comment: @vtha - Is it possible for `mod1` to broadcast a message that says, "I'm being unloaded. If you were using `mod1_open`, then use `original_open1` instead". Obviously the message parameters are pointers to functions. Perhaps [Can kernel module take initiative to send message to user space with netlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35098943/608639) and [Listening for netlink broadcasts in a kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27406105/608639). Maybe this is a question for [kernel newbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/MailingList).

Comment: @jww I like the approach you mentioned, but couldn't find any mechanism to broadcast the message from one module to all.

Comment: @Ajk - I don't know enough about kernel modules to help you further. I'd be surprised if the kernel lacked a similar method for IPC. That's kind of why I mentioned kernel newbies. Some of the kernel guys hang there, and they are gentler than asking on a full-fledged kernel list. Some of their answers are short or terse, but its often the toe-hold you need to investigate things further.

Comment: @jww Thanks. I will post my query on kernelnewbies.

Comment: For completeness, also see [Query regarding kernel modules intercepting system call](https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2017-July/018091.html) on the Kernel Newbies mailing list.